# Dose-response curve, Convergence failed

Tags: r

I'm trying to make Dose-Response curve and make model fitting with different models for my data. But for all types of models I'm always getting this error:

```
Error in optim(startVec, opfct, hessian = TRUE, method = optMethod, control = list(maxit = maxIt,  : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
Error in drmOpt(opfct, opdfct1, startVecSc, optMethod, constrained, warnVal,  : 
  Convergence failed
```

These are the codes that I'm using in R.

```
install.packages("drc")
library(drc)
library(ggplot2)

Sulf_Conc <- c(-3, -2.958607315, -2.698970004, -1.958607315, -0.995678626, 
  -0.300162274, 0.699056855)
Enzyme_Activities <- c(100, 55.30724303, 69.24958323, 82.88291229, 100.627504, 
  104.0535174, 67.16165961)
missing_enzyme <- sum(is.na(Enzyme_Activities))
cat("Missing values in Enzyme_Activities:", missing_enzyme, "\n")
missing_sulf <- sum(is.na(Sulf_Conc))
cat("Missing values in Sulf_Conc:", missing_sulf, "\n")
initial_params <- c(A = min(Enzyme_Activities),  # Lower asymptote
                    D = max(Enzyme_Activities),  # Upper asymptote
                    B = 1,  # Reasonable slope value (can be adjusted)
                    C = median(Sulf_Conc))  # EC50 (e.g., use median of concentrations)

ll.4 <- drm(
  Enzyme_Activities ~ Sulf_Conc, 
  data = DHA_Sulphadiazine, 
  fct = LL.4(), 
  start = initial_params
)
ll.4 <- drm(
  Enzyme_Activities ~ Sulf_Conc, 
  data = DHA_Sulphadiazine, 
  fct = LL.4()
)
```

Can someone help me out please to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem stems from the fact that you have negative concentrations, which do not make a lot of sense.
Assuming that these are the result of log10-transformation, you can fit a dose-response-curve on the untransformed data data in this way:

```
library(drc)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

Sulf_Conc <- c(-3, -2.958607315, -2.698970004, -1.958607315, -0.995678626, 
               -0.300162274, 0.699056855)
Enzyme_Activities <- c(100, 55.30724303, 69.24958323, 82.88291229, 100.627504, 
                       104.0535174, 67.16165961)
dat <- cbind(Enzyme_Activities, Sulf_Conc) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  mutate(Sulf_Conc = 10^Sulf_Conc)

ll.4 <- drm(
  Enzyme_Activities ~ Sulf_Conc, 
  data = dat, 
  fct = LL.4()
)

ll.4
```

Which returns this:

```
A 'drc' model.

Call:
drm(formula = Enzyme_Activities ~ Sulf_Conc, data = dat, fct = LL.4())

Coefficients:
b:(Intercept)  c:(Intercept)  d:(Intercept)  e:(Intercept)  
     -5.17374       74.85229       90.61444        0.01092
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You've truly made my day. The code is working beautifully now. I spent ten days on it without any luck, but your help has been a game-changer. If I run into more issues as I continue, how can I reach out for assistance?